# downloaded intellij from ubuntu software it is working fine but when I type java -version on terminal the command java is not recognied pops up

Tags: command-line, java, jdk

My intellij program works fine and runs programs as well but when I tried to check versions from terminal the terminal did not recognize "java" in "java -version" command. Also when I type javac it asks me to install jdk whereas the jdk is already installed. I started using ubuntu two days ago so I am not familiar with how this works. Thank you for the help.

The error message I get is given as follows

```
$ java --version

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.3+3-1ubuntu2
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.1+7-1ubuntu1
```

Comment: The java command to check the version uses two dashes `-`.  `java --version` You can also [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1273310/edit) your question and copy and paste any messages you are getting from your terminal showing that  you do indeed have the jdk installed.  Also, any error messages would be very helpful for us helping you.

Comment: I tried java --version and java -version I get the same error message on both commands.

Comment: According to your output java is not installed.  Did you by chance install the `intellij` snap app?  If you did, everything in the snap is confined to the snap itself so other apps like java would not be installed outside of that.  So, commands like `java --version` will not work.  I haven't used intellij in snap so unfortunately I would be no help there.

Comment: I just went to the ubuntu software store and downloaded intellij idea community edition.

Comment: Yep, it is from the `snap store`.  You can install other apps outside of it by running `sudo apt install default-jre` like the messages are saying, but those will have no impact on a snap app since everything they need is installed already in the snap itself.

Comment: Okay that worked but I did not understand that process. What did I just install separately and why was the direct install not working?

Comment: When you install an app using the Software Center you can scroll down and it will show you what type of app it is and where it comes from.  You might want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software) as they are two different ways of installing apps.  Since SNAP apps are self contained, they do not need to use extra dependencies in the Ubuntu OS as they already have everything self contained so Java would not be installed separately.  APT is a command line tool to install applications. Be patient, there's tons out there!

Comment: In any case, IntelliJ's JDK is bundled in its own folder (`/jbr`) and not present in the system PATH so `java` would not be found by default.